# How do I debug SQL query with the following error message

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query.

```
CREATE TABLE `requirements` 
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `requirement_id` VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    `state` VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    `city` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `salary_per_anum` FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    `is_closed` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, 
    `created_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT `pk_requirements` PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

and this is the error message

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, `state` VARCHAR NOT NULL, `city` VARCHAR NOT NULL, `salary_per_anum` F' at line 1

how can I debug what seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a length of the string colum like

```
`requirement_id` VARCHAR(100)
```

and the same with column `state` and `city`.

But since `requirement_id` looks like a number id column it must be of the same type as `id` in table `requirements`, probably `int`.

Also your constraint seems to be defined wrong. It should refer to the table `requirements`.